# Переустановка Windows с 7-ой на 10-ую с сохранением данных(фото, видео, word excel документов)

Tags: windows

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как переустановить винду с семерки на десятку, чтобы данные, которые хранятся на диске D, были сохранены.

Comment: Самый лучший вариант - это сохранить на внешний носитель или в облако. Потому что даже если инсталятор отработает норм, то аварию по электрике никто не отменял. В результате получишь кирпич.

Comment: Обновление системы не рассматриваете?

Answer (score 0):

Ну просто не форматируйте диск D и все.
Форматируйте только диск, на который устанавливаете десятку, если будете делать переустановку
А вообще там же есть режим миграции с 7 на 10... 
Железобетонный вариант - сохранить где-то все эти файлы. Жесткий диск иногда выходит из строя, полезно иметь копию файлов.